# .gitignore changed since using RubyMine

Tags: git, rubymine

My old gitignore for a project looked like this:

https://gist.github.com/Koxzi95/35f377d436962df0b06c

Ever since I've used RubyMine with the project the gitignore doesn't seem to be having an effect on Windows and OSX in the Atom editor and when running 'git status' in Git Bash.

What could be the reason for this?

Here is the gitignore:

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files for more about ignoring files.
#
# If you find yourself ignoring temporary files generated by your text editor
# or operating system, you probably want to add a global ignore instead:
# git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore_global'
*.rbc
capybara-*.html
.rspec
/log
/tmp
/db/*.sqlite3
# Need public system because lab machines.
# /public/system
/coverage/
/spec/tmp
**.orig
rerun.txt
pickle-email-*.html
# Ignore docs for now (Need them now)
# /doc/
.yardoc
# .yardopts
# TO-DO Comment out these rules if you are OK with secrets being uploaded to the repo
config/initializers/secret_token.rb
# config/secrets.yml
## Environment normalisation:
/.bundle
/vendor/bundle
# these should all be checked in to normalise the environment:
# Gemfile.lock
# .ruby-version, .ruby-gemset
# unless supporting rvm < 1.11.0 or doing something fancy, ignore this:
.rvmrc
# if using bower-rails ignore default bower_components path bower.json files
/vendor/assets/bower_components
*.bowerrc
bower.json
## Node/Grunt ignores:
/node_modules/
# Gruntfile.js
# package.json
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to be having an effect?" What happens exactly?

Comment: When I run 'git status' in the repo the files and folders which should be ignored are showing as not checked in.

Comment: Is your .gitignore file in your project root? Can you give an example of a filename that you expect to be ignored?

Comment: Can you show us what your current `.gitignore` looks like?

Comment: @yole the file is at my project root.

Comment: @JustinWood I've added it as a code block.

Comment: So what file is incorrectly reported as not checked in?

Comment: @yole A couple including folders http://i.imgur.com/0gtN1lL.jpg

db/development.sqlite3, 
db/test.sqlite3, 
log/, 
node_modules/, 
tmp/

Comment: This is only happening on a specific branch though, I don't know if that would affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason after using RubyMine the .gitignore was completely broken. I'm still not sure why but I had to rewrite the thing line by line.

If I made a change to the old one Atom was picking it up as a change on line 1. Even if it was on line 9 for example.

Not sure why it happened and I'd like an explanation if possible. But fixed now.

Comment: Can you check if the broken version had is line endings changed?  Maybe it's a `crlf` vs `cr` thing.

Comment: I am using a .editorconfig file with: `end_of_line = cr`. Should that be different then? Before I used rubymine I believe it was `crlf`

Comment: I can't tell you if it _should_ be different, but you've found a difference and it's worth investigating at your end...

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a play around.